# Which precomputations can be performed to invert product of positive symmetric matrices faster?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, computational-mathematics, positive-definite

## The problem

Given two real symmetric positive definite matrices $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, and real positive diagonal matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, I want to compute the inverse of the product

$$
C = A_1 \cdot \Sigma_1 \cdot A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot \Sigma_2 \cdot A_2
$$

efficiently, knowing $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ beforehand.

## What I already do

The first step I can do is to compute $\Sigma_1^{-1}$ and $\Sigma_2^{-1}$.
Then, when I get $A_1$ and $A_2$, I need just to invert their diagonal elements, compute $A_1^{-1} \cdot \Sigma_1^{-1} \cdot A_1^{-1}$ and $A_2^{-1} \cdot \Sigma_2^{-1} \cdot A_2^{-1}$ by multiplying the columns and rows of $\Sigma_1^{-1}$ and $\Sigma_2^{-1}$ by appropriate elements (efficient multiplication by diagonal matrices) and then compute the resulting product

$$
C^{-1} =  \left( A_2^{-1} \cdot \Sigma_2^{-1} \cdot A_2^{-1} \right) \cdot \left( A_1^{-1} \cdot \Sigma_1^{-1} \cdot A_1^{-1} \right)
$$

I can also collapse $A_2^{-1} \cdot A_1^{-1}$ to avoid one multiplication by a diagonal matrix.

Though, when I have matrices big enough (say, $10^3 \times 10^3$), this last multiplication is still a significant performance issue, despite I don't invert the $C$ matrix anymore, but only multiply two matrices to get $C^{-1}$. The complexity of matrix inverse is almost the same as the [matrix multiplication complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra).

I would like to get rid of the multiplication of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ (during actual computation of $C^{-1}$) by computing something beforehand.

## General problem

As the final result, I would like to be able to compute the products like the following efficiently, knowing all $\Sigma_i$ beforehand (able to compute everything I need for them before the inverse, but don't know $A_i$ beforehand)

$$
C = A_1 \cdot \Sigma_1 \cdot A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot \Sigma_2 \cdot A_2 \cdots A_n \cdot \Sigma_n \cdot A_n.
$$

Comment: You might find it useful to compute [Cholesky decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $A_i = L_i L_i^T$. With that, we would have
$$
C^{-1} = (L_2^{-T}L_2^{-1} \Sigma_2^{-1}L_2^{-T}L_2^{-1})
(L_1^{-T}L_1^{-1} \Sigma_1^{-1}L_1^{-T}L_1^{-1}).
$$
Note that both multiplication and inversion are more efficient when done with triangular matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, please, read the question carefully before answering it. The $A_i$ are diagonal and it's far more efficient to multiply them directly without using Cholesky decomposition (which is just an elementwise square root of the matrices in this case). One more issue: I don't know $A_i$ before the inverse &mdash; I know only $\Sigma_i$ and can do anything with them.

Comment: You're right, I misread and thought that the $\Sigma_i$ are diagonal

Comment: With that said, I think it might be useful to use the Cholesky decompositions of the $\Sigma_i$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it might, but I don't know how it could help. I can inverse $\Sigma_i$ before I know $A_i$. Then I will have multiplications by diagonal matrices ($O\left( n^2 \right)$) and multiplication of two positive definite matrices, which is significantly slower. If I use Cholesky decomposition, the straightforward multiplication simplifies twice, but I have twice more matrices, meaning three multiplications. It looks like straightforward application of Cholesky decomposition doesn't help here a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the original ($n=2$) problem: it would suffice to be able to quickly compute the product $\Sigma_{2}^{-1} (A_2^{-1}A_1^{-1})\Sigma_1^{-1}$. In other words, given known matrices $P,Q$, we would like to efficiently implement a function that produces the product $PDQ^T$ for the diagonal matrix input $D$ (the transpose redundant in your case, but is convenient for what follows).

Let $m$ be the size of these matrices. Let $p_1,\dots,p_n$ denote the columns of $P$, and let $q_1,\dots,q_n$ denote the columns of $Q$. Let $d_1,\dots,d_m$ denote the diagonal entries of $D$. We can compute
$$
PDQ^T = \sum_{k=1}^m d_k \cdot p_kq_k^T.
$$
If $P$ and $Q$ are already known, then rank 1 matrices $p_kq_k^T$ can be computed in advance.

---

Another approach that you might like is as follows: we have
$$
\operatorname{vec}(PDQ^T) = (Q \otimes P)\operatorname{vec}(D)
$$
where vec denotes [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). In other words, we can reduce the desired multiplication to multiplying the $m^2 \times m^2$ matrix $P \otimes Q$ by a sparse vector $\operatorname{vec}(D)$ (which has at most $m$ non-zero entries).

I'm not sure what algorithms exist for such computations, but I suspect that there is something out there for this kind of situation.